# Adding a fake call to android call log

Tags: android, calllog

I'm working on a headset button controller and I want to add a fake/invalid call to call log to prevent phone from dialing last call when I press headset button twice (double click) in htc android phones.
I tried this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, number);
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 0);
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE);
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 0);
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
cv.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");
this.getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

And the program crashes (App has stopped error).
I've set the permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

where is the problem?

Comment: I would consider allowing an app to write to the call log to be a huge security flaw.  Just don't press your headset button twice.

Comment: @Lotharyx I'm developing a headset button controller and I want to play next track by double clicking headset button instead of calling last person I've called.

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718617/how-to-detect-headset-button-double-click-in-htc-phones-with-broadcast-receiver) for solution for the double clicking problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * insert new call log
 */
public static void insertNumber(Activity activity) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 50);
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, "1234567");
    activity.getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            values);
}


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this unless you root your phone and `adb push` your app to the system partition (`/system/priv-app`)